# wifi ssid not showing

Tags: wireless-router, ssid

I bought a new router(Netgear WNR614). And I am having some weird problems.

SSID is broadcasted and showing fine on all android phones. It is not showing on my laptop *(Win 10)*. When I connect external wifi adapter, it is visible again. I have another external adapter which when when connected to my desktop *(win 7)* has same problem but when connected to laptop shows the SSID.

All other SSID are visible on all devices and adapters just fine. If I change my SSID it is visible fine for some time but once connected to it and disconnected SSID disappears again. Where could the problem be?

Router Config:
[image]

Comment: If it is not showing up then it means its broadcasting at a frequency your laptop does not support.  Are you running your access point at 5.0 GHz or 2.4 GHz?  What frequencies does your laptop support?

Comment: Router only broadcasts at 2.4GHz . And it does show sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection speed of the wireless ethernet adapter in the laptop may exceed the speed of the router based on the mode:

- IEEE 802.11b: 1, 2, 5.5, and 11Mbps
- IEEE 802.11g: 6, 9, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, and 54Mbps
- IEEE 802.11n: from 6.5 to 150Mbps
- IEEE 802.11ac: from 173Mbps to 1.3Gbps

In a mixed environment old and new devices, the router may stop broadcasting its SSID to devices requesting 150Mbps and higher connections, but continue to broadcast to devices requesting 54Mbps or lower connections.

**References**

- [READ ME FIRST! (Preliminary FAQs) - Ars Technica OpenForum](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=49810)
- [Wireless Networking in the Developing World - Wikisource, the free online library](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Wireless_Networking_in_the_Developing_World)
- [WiFi Network Troubleshooting - Fortinet Cookbook](http://cookbook.fortinet.com/wifi-network-troubleshooting/)
- [Wireless Technology Terms Glossary and Dictionary [S-Z]- Anritsu America](https://www.anritsu.com/en-US/test-measurement/technologies/bts-testing/bts-glossary-s-z)
- [Wireless Tutorial (pdf)](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~carey/CPSC641/slides/wireless/WirelessTutorial.pdf)
- [5th Generation WiFi: 802.11ac, "Gigabit" WiFi Primer](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5292/80211ac-gigabit-wifi-primer)
- [802.11ac: A Survival Guide](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001739/ch05.html)

Comment: Okay, if this is what the problem is, what is the best proposed solution--especially if a user isn't very tech-savvy?